# Creating XLSX file taking more time for 100000 records and taking max RAM memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating XLSX file with customized code with out Open XML SDK. it is working fine for 50000 records with 200 columns and taking max 13 GB RAM.

But when i was trying with 100000 rows and 200 columns taking max 16 GB RAM and never created the XLSX file and keep on increasing and decreasing RAM memory and also increasing and decreasing the CPU Usage.

I am writing 100000 rows and 200 columns into Stream and copying the stream to Package Part Stream at a same time with out splitting the XML file. That XML file size is 3 GB.

Can you please give solution for this with out using Open XML SDK.

When I tried with Open XML that is working with 100000 records with 200 columns for singe user. but at at time creating 100000 records with 200 columns for two users server is hanging.

My Customized code is taking more RAM but not hanging.

In below code "CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet_XMLWriter" Method is taking more RAM Size.

I am using below code for your reference. Please let me know if any changes are required.

```
//Package method

    Package package = null;
    using (package = ZipPackage.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    {

        packgPart = package.CreatePart(new Uri(relativePaths[relIndex], UriKind.Relative), contentTypes[6], CompressionOption.Maximum);
        XmlWriter xmlWriter;
        Stream stream = CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet_XMLWriter(data, "", out xmlWriter);
        CopyStream(stream, packgPart.GetStream());
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        xmlWriter.Close();
        xmlWriter = null;
        package.Flush();
        packgPart = null;
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
        stream = null;
        relIndex++;
        GC.Collect();
        package.Close();

    }

    // CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet method
    // Define other methods and classes here
private static Stream CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet_XMLWriter(List<StringBuilder> rows, string sheet,out XmlWriter xmlWriter)

{

    string[]  cols;

    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
             xmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
             xmlWriterSettings.Indent = false;
             xmlWriter = null;
             MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
             string nameSpace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
             xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream,xmlWriterSettings);

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","worksheet",nameSpace);
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","sheetData",nameSpace);


    for (m = 0; m < rows.Count; m++)
    {

        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","row",nameSpace);

        cols = rows[m].ToString().Split(new string[] { univDelimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);


        for (int i = 1; i <= cols.Length; i++)
         {
             cellValue = cols[i - 1];
             if (double.TryParse(cellValue,out dVal))
             {
                 dataType = "n";
             }
             else
             {
                 dataType = "str";
             }
             xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","c",nameSpace);
             xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("s", "13");
             xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("t", dataType);
             xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x", "v",nameSpace);
             xmlWriter.WriteValue(cellValue);
             xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
             xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
         }

        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        rows[m] = null;

    }
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}

//CopyStream method
private static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
{
     const int bufSize = 0x1000;
     byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
     int bytesRead = 0;
     while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0)
        target.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: maybe you can do file creation on a separate thread or an `async` `Task` so the server does not hang?

Comment: have you tried epplus?

Comment: `CompressionOption.Maximum` is the slowest one, so you can try `CompressionOption.Fast` for comparison

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are taking wrong approach in writing files, open xml sdk is good enough tool to create excels with large amount of data. 
i think you need to take SAX-Like Approach which uses combination of xmlreader and writer without running out of memory.

have a look at this wonderful blog which fits your specific requirements.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk/

Comment: was it helpful to you? there was another article on same, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877791/How-to-Create-Large-Excel-File-using-Openxml

Answer (score 2):

To reduce memory pressure consider not using MemoryStream in your XmlWriter. If you used a disk based stream then this would reduce memory pressure dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stream you are getting here `packgPart.GetStream()` as the back store for your xml writer.

Also I sense that you don't need to load the entire CSV in the memory.

Here is a version which is using streams only.

```
void Main()
{
    string inputFile = "D:\\_bigfile.csv";
    string path = "D:\\pack.zip";


    Package package = null;
    using (package = ZipPackage.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    {

        var packgPart = package.CreatePart(new Uri("/test.xml", UriKind.Relative), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml, CompressionOption.Maximum);
        using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet_XMLWriter(inputStream, "", packgPart.GetStream());
        }
    }
}
private const string univDelimiter = "|";

private static void CreateOpenXMLComWorkSheet_XMLWriter(Stream inputStream, string sheet, Stream packagePartStream)

{
    string cellValue = "";
    string dataType = "";
    double dVal = 0;
    string[]  cols;

    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
     xmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
     xmlWriterSettings.Indent = false;


     string nameSpace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
     using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(packagePartStream, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","worksheet",nameSpace);
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","sheetData",nameSpace);

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","row",nameSpace);

                cols = line.Split(new string[] { univDelimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 1; i <= cols.Length; i++)
                 {
                     cellValue = cols[i - 1];
                     if (double.TryParse(cellValue,out dVal))
                     {
                         dataType = "n";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         dataType = "str";
                     }
                     xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x","c",nameSpace);
                     xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("s", "13");
                     xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("t", dataType);
                     xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("x", "v",nameSpace);
                     xmlWriter.WriteValue(cellValue);
                     xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                     xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                 }

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```